# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink even tho the file exists

Tags: node.js, file, fs

As you can see, the directory exists and the file too, but for some reason, it's not being able to find the file to delete it.

[Directory exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlewF.png)

Code:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const path = "./resources/castigos/silencios/705143456384811039/526122991042428959.json"

fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }

  //file removed
})
```

I tried running the project as root, nothing...

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink './resources/castigos/silencios/705143456384811039/526122991042428959.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: './resources/castigos/silencios/705143456384811039/526122991042428959.json'
}
```

Comment: folder containing that file has a different name I guess from the screenshot

Comment: @RohitAmbre Hmm, not home right now so I can't check, but I'm pretty sure It's a typo from me. I'll check it out when I get home, thanks for warning me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your image file name is different, I believe wrong screen shared,

Also whenever dealing with fs and file paths use `path` module and `__dirname`

you can update your path as below

```
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/resources/castigos/silencios/705143456384811039/526122991042428959.json');
```

Comment: Hi there, the directory I pasted has a typo in the post (not in the code though (pretty sure)) but I'm gonna have to double check when I get home, I'll also implement the changes you said and accept the awnser if this works (or If I was just being dumb), thanks <3